# Threading With JavaScript Constructors? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, scaling

I have a Node.js application that is going to be ran off of my local machine, and I am using constructors to run multiple instances of the same code across x number of instances depending on how many times I want to complete the action (i am aware this is not true threading but it is a way to complete a similar action). I was wondering, if from a scaling stand point, if this will cause any issues down the line, like memory leaks, or other possible problems when scaling to hundreds of instances. I was also wondering that if in fact there is a problem with this method, how should I go about finding a workaround? Here is a little demo program

```
class Instance {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    start(id)
  }
}

function start(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
//spawns 10 instances
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  new Instance(i);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here.  Nothing in the code you posted has anything to do with treading.

Comment: Depends a lot what kind of "action" you are talking about. Your example code is entirely synchronous, no two instances will exist at the same time.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that requires to instantiate any object, just calling a function multiple times would suffice. But otherwise yes, there's nothing wrong with using a constructor if you need multiple instances with slightly different data that will do the same.

Comment: @Bergi that is what i need, thank you for your answer